# Executes dispatch_after when using dispatch_semaphore

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I'm having a problem when I want to execute a code inside my dispatch_after block.
First of all, I'm calling a UIActivityIndicator when a button is pressed in order to show it in screen and after the uiactivityindicator starts runnning I want to execute a server call, when I get a response from the server I return that value.
The problem is: When I call my UIAtivityIndicator to run and after that I make my server call, the UIActivityIndicator doesn't show in screen even when the `[UIActivityIndicatorInstance startAnimating];` was called and after that the server operation was called.
So I decided to use a `dispatch_after` in order to wait a certain time after de `[UIActivityIndicatorInstance startAnimating];` It works whe I do this, the problem becomes when I have to return the value, so for that reason a use `dispatch_semaphore` to tell me when the operation has finished and then return the value.
The big problem here is that the `dispatch_after` is not called.
This is my code, I appreciate you can help me with this problem or some other solution you have in mind.
The main idea that I want to accomplish is that I want to show an UIActivityIndicator while the server operation is executing and when it finishes I want to return that value in the same method.

```c
- (BOOL)getUserSatatus {
     // This is when the UIActivityIndicator is starts running
     [Tools startActivityIndicator];
     double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
     // This is used to save server response.
     __block BOOL serverResponse;

     dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
     dispatch_time_t executionTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
     // I want to execute the server call after a perios of time in order to show first de indicator on screen
     dispatch_after(executionTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSLog(@"This is where the server will call");
         // This is when I perform the service call and it returns a values that is
         // assigned to server response.
         serverResponse = [_backendManager getStatus];
         // This is the signal for the semaphore in order to execute the next lines.
         dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    });

    // Wait until the signal in order to execute the next line.
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return serverResponse; // Here will be the server return response.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> The big problem here is that the dispatch_after is not called.

Yes, that's because you're blocking the main thread with `dispatch_semaphore_wait`, so the `dispatch_after` never has a chance to run on the main thread and you're deadlocking.

We can walk you through ways to get around this, but you really shouldn't have synchronous network calls or semaphores in your code at all (for a myriad of reasons, not just for your activity indicator and for solving your deadlocking issue).

You should remove these synchronous network requests, remove the `dispatch_after`, and remove the semaphores. If you do all of that, and instead follow asynchronous patterns (like using completion blocks), your activity indicator view stuff will then work properly and you won't have any deadlock either.

The correct answer is to refactor the "back end manager" to perform its requests asynchronously (with completion blocks) and then use completion block pattern with `getUserStatus` method, too.

For example, let's say you fixed `getStatus` of the `_backendManager` to behave asynchronously:

```
- (void)getStatusWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = ...   // build the request however appropriate
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        BOOL status = ...;   // parse the response however appropriate
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completion) completion(status);
        });
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Then you can refactor the `getUserStatus` from your question to also take a completion handler:

```
- (void)getUserStatusWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {
    // This is when the UIActivityIndicator is starts running
    [Tools startActivityIndicator];

    [_backendManager getStatusWithCompletion:^(BOOL status){
        [Tools stopActivityIndicator];
        if (completion) completion(status);
    }
}
```

And then the code that needs to get the user status would do something like:

```
[obj getUserStatusWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
    // use `success` here
}];

// but not here
```